# Fill blank cells based on non blank cell above

Tags: excel, vba

I want to fill blank cells in sequential order based on the cell above.

The interval to be filled for column F is not consistent. Need to fill down two up to 20 rows based on the item number above.

Need VBA and not a formula.

This code would copy the item above the non blank and paste it down.

```
Sub FillBlanks()
Columns("F:F").Select
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C" 
End Sub
```

What I need is to autofill in sequence until the next nonblank.

Something like:

```
OA205S061169
OA205S061170
OA205S061171
OA205S061172
OA205S061173
OA205S061174
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can select your blank cells, as you are already doing, and then loop through each area, as follows...

```
Sub FillBlanks()

    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim dataRange As Range
    Dim currentArea As Range

    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row

    On Error Resume Next
    Set dataRange = Range("F1:F" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not dataRange Is Nothing Then
        For Each currentArea In dataRange.Areas
            With currentArea
                With .Offset(-1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count + 1)
                    .Cells(1).AutoFill Destination:=.Cells, Type:=xlFillDefault
                End With
            End With
        Next currentArea
    End If

End Sub
```

Note that it uses Column F to find the last used row.  However, depending on your data, you'll likely need to use some other column to determine the last used row.  To use Column A, for example, use the following instead...

```
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
```

Comment: Perfect... Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
Sub FillTest()
    Dim rngDB As Range
    Dim vDB, vSplit
    Dim i As Long, x As Long, n As Integer
    Dim s As String

    Set rngDB = Range("f1", Range("f" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    vDB = rngDB

    For i = 1 To UBound(vDB, 1)
        If vDB(i, 1) <> "" Then
            vSplit = Split(vDB(i, 1), "S")
            s = vSplit(0) & "S"
            x = vSplit(1)
            n = 0
        Else
            n = n + 1
            vDB(i, 1) = s & Format(x + n, "000000")
        End If
    Next i
    rngDB = vDB
End Sub
```

Comment: Perfect... Thank you very much for your help.